# Error 500 when sending email with CakePHP 3

Tags: php, email, smtp, cakephp-3.0

I am developing a small web page with CakePHP 3. It features a very simple contact form that send an email using SMTP server from 1and1.es.

This is my Transport configuration at config/app.php:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.1and1.es',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'myuser@mydomain.es',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

It works fine at local development sever (Xampp on Ubuntu 14.04): I am receiving  all emails. But it throws a 500 Internal Server Error when on production server (1and1 shared server) using the same above configuration. Same PHP version on both servers.

I've found similar questions here at Stackoverflow, but nothing helped me. By the way, I can't access to apache error logs in the server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I've just found that Cakephp error.log file has some related info:

```
2016-10-09 22:18:38 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] Connection timed out
Request URL: /home/index
Referer URL: http://monitomolon.es/
Stack Trace:
#0 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(207): Cake\Network\Socket->connect()
#1 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(162): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->_connect()
#2 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Email.php(1344): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Cake\Mailer\Email))
#3 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/src/Form/ContactForm.php(56): Cake\Mailer\Email->send('Nombre: Diego A...')
#4 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Form/Form.php(179): App\Form\ContactForm->_execute(Array)
#5 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/src/Controller/HomeController.php(13): Cake\Form\Form->execute(Array)
#6 [internal function]: App\Controller\HomeController->index()
#7 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(435): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(122): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#9 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(96): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\HomeController))
#10 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(83): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#11 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(53): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#13 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#15 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#17 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#18 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#19 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#20 /homepages/14/d393557898/htdocs/monitomolon/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#21 {main}
```

Comment: We can't help you if you can't find / access the error or narrow down the issue to something beyond part of an array.

Comment: So what does the http servers error log file say? _We_ certainly cannot tell you...

Comment: so, the connection timed out which I would expect probably means your 1and1 host is blocking SMTP connections.

Comment: Thanks, @JonStirling. But, why it works on my localhost and fails on remote server?

Comment: @Diego Again, probably 1and1 blocking the connection. I'm pretty sure 1and1 doesn't run your personal computer ;)

Comment: Well, I am not sure at all about that... :) I'll contact them again. Thank you.

Comment: Well it's fair to say that I could be wrong. But whatever the deal is, this doesn't appear to be a PHP problem since it works on your local :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1and1.es customer service informed me that smtp server is intended for email clients use only and therefore it's use within a script is forbidden in my shared server. So, I solved this issue by using native PHP function mail() and default CakePHP transport. Simply defined `EmailTransport` this way:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'mail' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Can you give some details on how to solve this issue? I have the same problem with 1and1?

Comment: Updated answer, @TheDevMan.

Comment: You dont need any other details at all.